# IndexError at /search/ list index out of range

Tags: python, django, search, django-filter

При вводе названия по которому хочу отфильтровать свой список игр, выводится ошибка

> IndexError at /search/
> list index out of range.

Вывожу по названию игры, то есть 'tltle'

Форма:

```html
<form action="{% url 'search_result' %}" method="get">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Поиск по названию">
</form>
```

Функция:

```py
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Game
    template_name = 'games_list/index.html'
    allow_empty = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return Game.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
```

urls.py:

```py
path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_result')
```

Моя модель:

```py
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True, verbose_name='Название игры')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="URL вашей игры")
    description = models.TextField ... и т.д.
```

У меня есть название `CoolGame`, ввожу его и появляется страница с ошибкой, пересмотрел несколько способов и только у меня выводит данную ошибку.

Я только пробую делать сайт, поэтому могу многого не понимать. Если нужен еще какой-то код, пишите.

Comment: В первую очередь приведите полный текст ошибки